# Sum groups of flagged items and then find max values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-itertools

I'd like to sum the values grouped by positive and negatives flows and then compare them to figure out the largest negative and largest positive flows.

I think itertools is probably the way to do this but can't figure it out.

```
#create a data frame that shows week and value
n_rows = 30
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'week': pd.date_range('1/4/2019', periods=n_rows, freq='W'),
                      'value': np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(n_rows))})

#flag positives and negatives
def flowFinder(row):
    if row['value'] > 0:
        return "Positive"
    else:
        return "Negative"
dftest['flag'] = dftest.apply(flowFinder,axis=1)
dftest
```

[In this example df](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17n0Rg4VNzqaswijaIxdYs-0Edh3ecU0f), you'd determine that 15-19 adds up toe 249 which is the max value of all the positive flows. The max negative flow is line 5 with -98.

Edit by Scott Boston 
It is best if you added code that generates your dataframe instead of links to a picture.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'week':pd.date_range('2019-01-06',periods=21, freq='W'), 
                   'value':[64,43,94,-19,3,-98,1,80,-7,-43,45,58,27,29,
                            -4,20,97,30,22,80,-95],
                   'flag':['Positive']*3+['Negative']+['Positive']+['Negative']+
                           ['Positive']*2+['Negative']*2+['Positive']*4+
                           ['Negative']+['Positive']*5+['Negative']})
```

Comment: (dftest.value>0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.groupby((df['flag'] != df['flag'].shift()).cumsum())['value'].sum().agg(['min','max'])
```

Output:

```
min    -98
max    249
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Using rename:

```
df.groupby((df['flag'] != df['flag'].shift()).cumsum())['value'].sum().agg(['min','max'])\
  .rename(index={'min':'Negative','max':'Positive'})
```

Output:

```
Negative    -98
Positive    249
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Update answer comment:

```
df_out = df.groupby((df['flag'] != df['flag'].shift()).cumsum())['value','week']\
           .agg({'value':'sum','week':'last'})
df_out.loc[df_out.agg({'value':['idxmin','idxmax']}).squeeze().tolist()]
```

Output:

```
      value       week
flag                  
4       -98 2019-02-10
9       249 2019-05-19
```

Comment: This is perfect. thank you! A quick followup: how can you show the date at which the min and the max occurred?

Comment: In the case of positive which date do you want?  Four dates going in to calculating that number.

Comment: the last date it min  and the last date for max.

Comment: This seriously is amazing and perfect. Eager to keep learning this. Thank you for your help @scott-boston